# Media Queries in styled components are changing by themselves

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, media-queries, styled-components

I am writing some media-queries for a styled-component called "Border", when i write some code for `max-width:320px` my media-query for `max-width:420px` gets edited too and it ruins the margins. Could someone help me with this? I would like the gray box to be in the middle and fill the mobile screen

https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-ride-wg186?file=%2Fsrc%2FStyled.js

Comment: A good practice when it comes to media queries is to start with the bigger screens first. That way you will only have to do minimal changes to each device as the browser traverses down your CSS, because the other queries will inherit the styles from a top-down level. An example would be styling for the 480px max width. For example's sake lets say that query is very code-heavy. Now for 375px max width you might only want to change a few things. Instead of re-writing a lot of code, you now have a lot of styling that's inherited from the 480px max width media query.

Comment: @martin thanks man finally got it, was cleaning the code then realized what went wrong lol

Comment: Another approach is Mobile First, which is the reverse approach of my first comment. You start with the smaller screens and as you expand, you apply minor and major style fixes where the site breaks. Mobile First is considered best practice, and it takes some time to getting used to. It promotes the responsive design ultimately a lot more than Desktop First as Desktop First can easily get caught in a more adaptive design approach, making it very heavy for mobile phones. Afterall, PC's tend to have more processing power, which means leaving more CSS for PC than mobile is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the wished style which you want for 420px and bigger, because, if you don't say, which style it needs to have, it'll take over the styles from the Media-query which is set at 320px.

That's because CSS orientates with the screen size going up/bigger.

It'll look like this:

```
export const NavButtons = styled.button`
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;

  &:hover {
    text-decoration: line-through;
  }
  @media (max-width: 320px) {
    margin-top: 10vh;
  }

  @media (max-width: 420px) {
   //yourstyle
  }
`;
```

Comment: i was more talking about the const "Border" not the navbuttons, thanks for the detailed answer tho

Comment: @joshk98 can you explain what you want to to with them, or what doesn't work?

Comment: i want the grey box to fill the mobile screen and be in the center of the mobile screen